# Positioning :before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to achieve this container look using the `:before` pseudo-element:

[image]

I'm talking about the border and the "Express checkout" text, not the buttons.

Here's the layout I'm working with:

```css
.btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="div-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

No matter which element I give the `...:before {content: "Express checkout"}`  I'm having a very hard time trying to position and center the text as well as the container. I've been trying for days and I can't get it to work...

Could someone please show me a way or 2 of how this can be done? I would greatly appreciate it.

I can not change the HTML code. I can only work with what I have..

Comment: Which element/selector are you adding the pseudo element to?

Comment: There is no `pseudo-element` in your code!

Comment: @Manas, I've stated in my question that I've tried adding the `pseudo-element` to all of the elements. But I always run into positioning or display issues. So I decided to just give a clean canvas with my code.  @Terry,  I've tried adding the `border` to `div-2` and the `pseudo-element` to `div-1`, it seems like the best way.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you want to do this with a pseudo-element of using a fieldset and legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually would not solve it with pseudo-elements which require a "hacky" positioning but a simple `fieldset`and `legend`:

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

legend {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  max-width: 400px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Express checkout</legend>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
</fieldset>
```

If you cant change the HTML as in your comment, then apply the border to `div-2`. Then use postion: relative to the `div-1` and add the test as pseudo-element to `div-1` like in the snippet below:

```css
.div-1,
.div-1 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div-1 {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.div-1::after {
  content: "Express checkout";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 10px; 
  margin: 0;
}

.div-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
}


.btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <div class="div-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, I can not change the HTML code. I can only work with what I have..

Comment: @JOKKER I see, I added you also a solution with pseudo-elements with your code structure.